# Azure Files Mount to Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, file-storage, azure-files

I followed [this](http://fabriccontroller.net/using-the-azure-file-service-in-your-cloud-services-web-roles-and-worker-role/) tutorial and everything seemed to be working fine locally, however when i hosted my web app on Azure and tried to mount/access file storage i get "Access is denied" however i am certain my credentials are correct as they work locally. Is there something extra i must add when on an azure environment (auth wise)?

I suspect it is something to do with the fact that the tutorial uses dlls that may not be available on an azure environment, if this is the issue links/hints to how i could go about resolving would be very appreciated.

worth mentioning:
both Web app and file storage are in the same region on azure.

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in other questions/answers here - you cannot mount an Azure Files volume with Web Apps (you have to use direct API/SDK calls).

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying that. Would something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Makogon mentioned that  Azure Files volumes can't be mounted to Azure Web App.

> Would something like this learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/… be appropriate?

If we want to operate the files in the Azure file storage. I recommand that you could use Azure File storage SDK to do that. We also could get demo code from [Develop for Azure Files with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#access-the-file-share-programmatically).

```
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

// Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("logs");

// Ensure that the share exists.
if (share.Exists())
{
    // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
    CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("CustomLogs");

    // Ensure that the directory exists.
    if (sampleDir.Exists())
    {
        // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
        CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("Log1.txt");

        // Ensure that the file exists.
        if (file.Exists())
        {
            // Write the contents of the file to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine(file.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}
```